# How can I programmatically prevent the removal of fields from content types and entity types?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Id like to write module code that will not allow anyone (administrator or not) to remove fields and field instances.  Unfortunately this restriction will have to be done in code, just setting permissions in the ui wont cut it.

Is there a hook I can use to prevent the deletion of fields from entities?

Comment: there is a bool flag `deleted` into `field_config` table , and daily cron field_cron proceed to instance deletion + instances deletion.
you can use  `hook_field_delete` maybe to avoid update flag you can see this hook into field.api.php

Comment: Why wouldn't permissions work for this?
What we do is we create a new administrator role and give it the required permissions.